# Oracle SQL - Does the JOIN order in a FROM clause impact performance optimization?

Tags: oracle, performance, optimization, sql-tuning

A long while ago I was once told during a SQL course that the JOIN order in a FROM clause of a query can impact the performance of the query. So for example if I had the following

```
SELECT * FROM 
TABLE_1 INNER JOIN --5000 rows
TABLE_2 ON TABLE_1.COL1=TABLE_2.COL1 INNER JOIN --200 rows
TABLE_3 ON TABLE_2.COL1=TABLE_3.COL1--50 rows
.....
```

This should be reordered to the following

```
SELECT * FROM 
TABLE_3 INNER JOIN --50 rows
TABLE_2 ON TABLE_2.COL1=TABLE_3.COL1 INNER JOIN --200 rows
TABLE_1 ON TABLE_1.COL1=TABLE_2.COL1 --5000 rows
.....
```

So the leading/driving table is the least amount of rows first (hypothetically). I have read though that unless a HINT is used to force the order, the cost based optimizer within Oracle would just re-arrange the JOIN as it saw fit.

Just curious, does the JOIN order without using HINTS matter in a SQL statement?

Answer (score 2):

Exactly, a *long time ago* there was impact, when RBO (Rule based optimizer) was used.

In modern Oracle releases, CBO (Cost based optimizer) chooses the best execution plan and does that *dirty* job for you so - no, you don't have to reorder tables any more.

Answer (score 0):

> does the JOIN order without using HINTS matter in a SQL statement?

No. That's basic optimisation for the database; the optimizer will decide what is the best strategy to join the tables, regardless of the order in which they appear in the `from` clause.

Answer (score 0):

The oracle optimizer component "Query Transformer" transform your query, it does this automatically if needed with the statistics available´when it finds your to be transformed.